# Guzzle throws 401 or 406 exception

Tags: php, curl, guzzle

cURL works fine:

```
curl -H "X-ApiToken: myapitoken" https://api.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/records
```

Guzzle does not:

```
$client = new Client();
$request = $client->createRequest('GET', "https://api.fulcrumapp.com/api/v2/records");
$request->setHeader("X-ApiToken:" , "myapitoken");
$response = $client->send($request);
```

This responds with a 401 error: not authorized.  This is my first time using Guzzle but in my searches I haven't seen this error.  Seems like a simple request so I'm not sure why it is failing.

Thank you!

Comment: Remove the colon in the header name argument and try again.

Comment: I tried removing the colon (I should have mentioned that originally): it changes it to a 406 (not acceptable) error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to add another header to explicitly tell it to handle json

```
$request->setHeader("Accept" , "application/json");
```

Thank you for pointing out that the 401 was a false error - the real error was the 406, which made me read how to actually fix that.

Answer (score 0):

The `setHeader` method takes the header name without the colon. Change `"X-ApiToken:"` to `"X-ApiToken"`.

Comment: I tried removing the colon (I should have mentioned that originally): it changes it to a 406 (not acceptable) error.